# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle Global template

Tags: symfony, twig, extends, fosuserbundle

How can I force FOSUserBundle to render all its pages as a part of my global template.

i tried to insert layout.html.twig from FOS UB to {% block login %} in my ::base.html.twig file which is above my default content in {% block body %}. when user enters page and logs in its ok but if he make for example password error he see only login form not the whole page.

I have also overriden layout of FOS UB to extend ::base.html.twig but how to make next steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Override template](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) section of the doc.

**Edit**

Login action redirection is done by Symfony's internal Authentication/firewall system. If you enter wrong password the Symfony automatically redirects to login action you defined in firewall. For more info you can check [Security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) section of the book. In this case you have to modify `login.html.twig` of FOSUserBundle to use your base template.

Comment: i know that part but have no idea how to glue different templates managed by different controllers. like {% block login %} rendered by fos ub, {% block content %} by default controller etc. problem is how from one action render whole page even if i do not explicitely run show login action

Comment: Linkrot killed your link. Please summarise what you remember from it.